# Loop through Dojo DataGrid and tie field name values to an array

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a data grid that I want to use for a file list and if that file already exists in the data grid (store) I want it to just give them a dijit dialog box stating that the file already exists. My question is it easier to tie into the store and see if the file is already there or store the values of the field in an array and look there if the file exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not store the values in an extra array (= overhead).

You can access the values of the datagrid by using the store:

> var store = new some.Datastore();
>
> store.fetch({onComplete: function(items, request){
>
> console.log("Number of items located: " + items.length);
>
> }});

Source:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/data/api/Read.html#fetching-all-the-items-from-the-store